# Taking reciprocal of each elements in a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix below.

```
a = sparse.diags([1,2,3],[-1,0,1],shape=(6,6),format ="csr")
```

I want to take the reciprocal of each of the elements in the sparse matrix. 
I search it on the internet and notice that taking the reciprocal is barely mentioned. 
I know numpy has a reciprocal function. np.reciprocal() But it does not work in my case.

It does not have to have such a recipical function. If somebody can provide an elementwise division function of two sparse matrices of same size, or elementwise power function(power of -1), that will also be great.
Thank you So much.

Comment: sorta duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070690/sqrt-for-element-wise-sparse-matrix

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you only want to take the reciprocal of the nonzero elements, you can use</strike>

```
M.nonzero() = 1 / M.nonzero()
```

It depends on which sparsity form you are using whether this will be fast or not!

Or borrowing from [Efficient way of taking Logarithm function in a sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830620/efficient-way-of-taking-logarithm-function-in-a-sparse-matrix?rq=1), you can use

```
new_data = 1/M.data
M = csr_matrix((new_data, (M.row, M.col)), shape = M.shape)
```

Or (late edit, thanks to joeln), the above can be done in place with

```
np.reciprocal(M.data, out=M.data)
```

and then the entries of `M` will be inverted.

Comment: You can't assign to `M.nonzero()`. The next option will work, but the operation can be performed in-place with, `np.reciprocal(M.data, out=M.data)`.